# Magento 2 : What's the proper location to put repositories?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, coding-standards, repositories

In Magento 2.1:

When I look at the customer module, I note that the **customer repository** is located in the folder for resource models:

```
Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository
```

But when I look at the catalog module, the **repositories** are located in the model folder:

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
```

So what's the proper convention for when it comes to the location of repositories?

Answer (score 1):

The repository classes should sit under `Model` IMHO.

But I reckon **it's more important to setup service contract classes for those repositories than placing them in the right folder** because if you setup proper service contracts for those classes, **their location does not really matter as you will be using the service contracts classes instead ;)**

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you. Service contracts FTW. But nevertheless it would be good for the community to have some kind of convention on where to put things. That seems to be rather lacking right now...

Comment: @GielBerkers it'll get better over time. Most of the inconsistencies in M2 (different folders e.g. `Observer` and `Model/Observer` to take another example, direct use of Object Manager) come from the fact that originally M2 is a port of M1 so there's some leftovers here and there.